# How to Enable APTran custom fields after Bill has been Released

Tags: acumatica

I have two Custom Fields on APTran, after the Bill is Released they both become Read Only.

Both fields need to be editable at any time, regardless of the Bill Status.

After searching and finding similar examples for other screens, I tried making a version for screen AP301000, but the fields remain Read Only after the Bill is Released.

APTran DAC Extension:

```
namespace CustomFields
{
  public class APTranExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APTran>
  {
    
    #region UsrCustomField1
    [PXDBString(50)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Custom Field 1", Enabled = true)]
    public string UsrCustomField1 { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrCustomField1 : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrCustomField2
    [PXDBString(20)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Custom Field 2", Enabled = true)]
    public string UsrCustomField2 { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrCustomField2 : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

  }
}
```

APInvoiceEntry Graph Extension:

```
namespace CustomFields
{
    public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APInvoiceEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers

        public void APTran_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
            {
                APTran row = e.Row as APTran;
        
                if (row != null)
                {
                    APInvoice doc = Base.Document.Current;
        
                    if (doc != null && doc.Released == true)
                    {
                        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTranExt.usrCustomField1>(sender, row, true);
                        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTranExt.usrCustomField2>(sender, row, true);
                    }
                }
            }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Also tried setting SetReadOnly to False, but that made no difference:

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTranExt.usrCustomField1>(sender, row, true);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetReadOnly<APTranExt.usrCustomField1>(sender, row, false);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTranExt.usrCustomField2>(sender, row, true);
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetReadOnly<APTranExt.usrCustomField2>(sender, row, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your APTran_RowSelected handler, I tested it in 23R1.

The problem is Transaction cache is disabled when the document is released.

It is not enough to simple enable it again, because it would enable all fields in APTran records (1st row), so we need to disable all of them (2nd row).

```
sender.AllowUpdate = true; // it is disabled in APInvoice_RowSelected, you need to reenable here
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(sender, row, false); // disable all fields
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTranExt.usrCustomField1>(sender, row, true); // enable only your field
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<APTranExt.usrCustomField2>(sender, row, true); // enable only your field
```